# Error when using ifelse() condition in ggplot code

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

Unfortunately I am getting an error, when trying to use `ifelse` condition in `ggplot` code, where I am passing `element_blank()` function to `axis.test.x` parameter in `theme()`.

```
 hideAxis=T
 ggplot(data = iris , aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity", fill ='#2219CCCC') + 
        xlab("Sepal.Length") + 
        ylab("Sepal.Length") +
        theme(axis.text.x = ifelse(hideAxis==TRUE,element_blank(),element_text(angle =20)))
```

Any suggestions or help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend simpler, just `axis.text.x = if (hideAxis) element_blank() else element_text(angle=20)`. (`if (cond == TRUE)` is unnecessary, there is no difference between the two.)

Comment: That worked!!!!

Comment: but `ifelse` should work right? why one works and other doesn't?

Comment: In general, `ifelse` is really only beneficial when you expect that the condition, "yes", and "no" components are vectors (each of same length or length1), leaning more towards length 2 or higher. In this case, since `hideAxis` to me implies always `TRUE` or `FALSE`, length 1, a singular `if` is justified. (BTW: `ifelse` is not always your friend, its use can have consequences when dealing with vectors of other than `numeric` or `character`, since for instance `POSIXt` will be converted to numeric silently.)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans makes sense :)

Comment: I only trust `ifelse` when I *know* that both of the "yes" and "no" vectors are simple vectors of simple objects (such as `numeric`, `integer`, `logical`, or `character`); anything else (such as `POSIXt`, `Date`, `list`, or complex things like plot components as in this case) and `ifelse` is not reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `eval()` and `parse()` to fix this situation. The `eval()` function evaluates an expression. The `parse()` function converts an R object of the character class to an R object of the expression class. Through use, If-Else to change expression.

```
# control  
hideAxis = T

if(hideAxis == T){   
axis_text_x_element <- 'element_blank()' 
} else { 
axis_text_x_element <- 'element_text(angle =20)' 
}

# plot  
ggplot(data = iris , aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Length)) +    
geom_bar(stat="identity", fill ='#2219CCCC') + 
xlab("Sepal.Length") + 
ylab("Sepal.Length") +   
eval(parse(text=(paste("theme(axis.text.x = ",axis_text_x_element,")"))))
```

Output(hideAxis == T): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZpE3.png)

Output(hideAxis == F): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl1sY.png)